# Sign google cloud storage blob using access token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

## Goal: Generate Signed-URL Using OAuth2.0 Access Token

The examples and source codes I find for signing Google Cloud Storage blobs all require service account credentials file (the private key to be specific). For instance:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-get-object-python

However, since I follow [the authorization flow discussed here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#sa-credentials-blob), I only have OAuth2.0 access token (and I do NOT have the credentials file and private key of a service account with access to GCS bucket/object). Hence, I was wondering how I can sign blobs using OAuth2.0 access tokens.

## The Code Used:

I use the following to sign blob:

```py
# First, get access token:
service_account = "<email address of a service account>"
access_token = build(
    serviceName='iamcredentials',
    version='v1',
    http=http
).projects().serviceAccounts().generateAccessToken(
    name="projects/{}/serviceAccounts/{}".format(
        "-",
        service_account),
    body=body
).execute()["accessToken"]

credentials = AccessTokenCredentials(access_token, "MyAgent/1.0", None)

# Second, use the access token to sign a blob
url = "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/{}:signBlob".format(service_account)
encoded = base64.b64encode(blob)
sign_blob_request_body = {"payload": encoded}

response = requests.post(url,
                         data=json.dumps(sign_blob_request_body),
                         headers={
                             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                             'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(credentials.access_token)})
signature = response.json()["signedBlob"]

# Third, use the signature to create signed URL:
encoded_signature = base64.b64encode(signature)
signed_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/<BUCKET>/<OBJECT>?" \
             "GoogleAccessId={}&" \
             "Expires={}&" \
             "Signature={}".format(service_account, 
                                   expiration, 
                                   encoded_signature)
```

### The Error Message Received:

```xml
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>
        The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
    </Message>
    <StringToSign>GET 1561832204 /<BUCKET>/<OBJECT></StringToSign>
</Error>
```

Comment: You can also consider using blob.generate_signed_url, [here you have example code how to sign url](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/29e4cd6c236567ec35b7fb68ab78823a180b2594/storage/cloud-client/snippets.py#L251)

Comment: how do you run that method with access token? do you have a working example? to be specific, how do you construct the client with access token?

Comment: Using blob.generate_signed_url you do not need access token. To use access token and no API Key please check updated answer for example.

Answer (score -1):

In case you do NOT want to use API secret key, [follow procedure described in this sample](https://github.com/salrashid123/gcpsamples/tree/master/gcs_keyless_signedurl) that is using [iamcredentials.signBlob() API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/credentials/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob) signing URL 'remotely' for a service account with no need to distribute API secret key.

Signature string (that has to be signed) has this format:

```
signature_string = ('{verb}\n'
                    '{content_md5}\n'
                    '{content_type}\n'
                    '{expiration}\n'
                    '{resource}')
```

Comment: how do you generated a signed URL using the signed blob you obtain calling the API? because when I try that API and generated a signed URL, I get an error saying `SignatureDoesNotMatch`.

Comment: reg. `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, you do not use it when using the flow I linked.

Comment: please see my updated question, as you may notice I am using the authorization header, so that may not be the source of this issue.

Comment: As I mentioned in the beginning of my question, I am using access token, hence I do not have an API key.

Comment: In this case you need to follow this example: [code for keyless url sign](https://github.com/salrashid123/gcpsamples/tree/master/gcs_keyless_signedurl)