# Django model FileField is set to "null" instead of url to the file when using Google Cloud Storage

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage

I am running a File manager app on Local machine using Google Cloud Sql Proxy and storing the files in a Google Cloud Storage bucket.
The file is being saved in the bucket, but the FileField is set to "null". I want it to show the url by which I can access the file.

I am following this answer [Configure Django and Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247702/configure-django-and-google-cloud-storage/50116653#50116653)

I have set the Google Cloud Storage bucket to public.

Django Model:

```py
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
```

Setting.py:

```py
#MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'printhub-files'

GS_PROJECT_ID = 'preasy-53c43'
GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME = 'printhub-files'
# GS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME = '<name-of-static-bucket>'
# STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/'.format(GS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME)
MEDIA_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/'.format(GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME)
```

Expected Result:

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "docfile": "https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/documents/2019/11/03/myfile.pdf",
}
```

Actual Result:

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "docfile": null,
}
```

If I change my Settings.py to (uncomment line 1,2. Comment line 4), the file is saved on my local machine media/ folder, and "docfile" is set to the bucket url:

```py
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

#DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'printhub-files'

GS_PROJECT_ID = 'preasy-53c43'
GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME = 'printhub-files'
# GS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME = '<name-of-static-bucket>'
# STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/'.format(GS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME)
MEDIA_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/'.format(GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME)
```

I get the output:

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "docfile": "https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/documents/2019/11/03/myfile.pdf",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're not configuring the settings.py file correctly. Check this [documentation](https://eldarion-gondor.github.io/docs/how-to/configure-gcs-backend/) to use Google Cloud Storage Bucket for Djanjo project.

As you can see in the documentation, settings.py should be like this:

settings.py

```
.....
GCS_ROOT = "https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket_name}/".format(
  bucket_name=os.environ.get("GCS_BUCKET")
)

MEDIA_PREFIX = "media"
MEDIA_URL = "{gcs_root}{prefix}/".format(
  gcs_root=GCS_ROOT,
  prefix=MEDIA_PREFIX,
)
......
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I'm using [this](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html) package. It is working after i set environment variabel GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in my app.yaml file. However, the file url now has a signature string attached at the end.

Ex: https://storage.googleapis.com/path/to/sample.pdf?Expires=1573391793&GoogleAccessId=<app-name>appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Signature=cbb...

Instead of: https://storage.googleapis.com/path/to/sample.pdf

Comment: You can solve SignatureDoesNotMatch error looking at this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801281/sign-google-cloud-storage-blob-using-access-token)

Let me know if it works for you!